# rails 4 live stream doesn't work with Puma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, live-streaming, puma

I'm trying to implement a small test on rails `ActiveController::Live` with Puma server. I started Puma server by `rails s puma`, and used `curl localhost:3000/messages/events` to do test. However there was a long pause before the data is returned all at once, which was the same as using WEBrick. So Why doesn't the Puma server live stream the results?

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  include ActionController::Live

  def index
    @messages = Message.all
  end

  def create
    @message = Message.create!(params[:message].permit(:content, :name))
  end

  def events
    3.times do |n|
      response.stream.write "#{n}...\n\n"
      sleep 2
    end
  ensure
    response.stream.close
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the response headers

```
def events
   response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/event-stream'
   3.times do |n|
     response.stream.write "#{n}...\n\n"
     sleep 2
   end
ensure
   response.stream.close
end
```